# Creating and sending a SOAP message in java to a very simple web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, xml-namespaces

I am currently trying to create and send a SOAP message to a very simple web service I've created myself.

Obviously the webservice have a wsdl file, which you can see here:

```
wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns="http://service.com" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" targetNamespace="http://service.com">
<wsdl:documentation>Please Type your service description here</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://service.com">
<xs:element name="echoTest">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="echoString" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="echoTestResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="echoTestRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:echoTest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="echoTestResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:echoTestResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="RequestHandlerPortType">
<wsdl:operation name="echoTest">
<wsdl:input message="ns:echoTestRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:echoTest"/>
<wsdl:output message="ns:echoTestResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:echoTestResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="RequestHandlerSoap11Binding" type="ns:RequestHandlerPortType">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<wsdl:operation name="echoTest">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:echoTest" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="RequestHandlerSoap12Binding" type="ns:RequestHandlerPortType">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<wsdl:operation name="echoTest">
<soap12:operation soapAction="urn:echoTest" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="RequestHandlerHttpBinding" type="ns:RequestHandlerPortType">
<http:binding verb="POST"/>
<wsdl:operation name="echoTest">
<http:operation location="echoTest"/>
<wsdl:input>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="RequestHandler">
<wsdl:port name="RequestHandlerHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:RequestHandlerSoap11Binding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8181/PayCheckHandlerMainWebService/services/RequestHandler.RequestHandlerHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="RequestHandlerHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:RequestHandlerSoap12Binding">
<soap12:address location="http://localhost:8181/PayCheckHandlerMainWebService/services/RequestHandler.RequestHandlerHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="RequestHandlerHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:RequestHandlerHttpBinding">
<http:address location="http://localhost:8181/PayCheckHandlerMainWebService/services/RequestHandler.RequestHandlerHttpEndpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I've then used the google chrome plugin called Wizdler, to find out how the structure of soap messages should look like. THe Soap message for this example, should look like this.

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <Body>
        <echoTest xmlns="http://service.com">
            <echoString>[string?]</echoString>
        </echoTest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

So a pretty simple and straightforward SOAP message.. Nevertheless, Ican get it to work. 
I am trying to create the SOAP message with the following code:

```
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String serverURI = "http://service.com";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        soapBody.addNamespaceDeclaration("", serverURI);
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("echoTest");

        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("echoString");
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("HELLO?!?");

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("RequestHandler", serverURI);

        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        /* Print the request message */
        System.out.print("Request SOAP Message:");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();
```

The above code, produces the following SOAP message:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns="http://service.com">
      <echoTest xmlns="">
          <echoString xmlns="http://service.com">HELLO?!?</echoString> 
      </echoTest>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I don't know why the echoString get the xmlns="http://service.com".. it should be in the echoTest tag instead.. and I guess this could be a part of the problem.

The response message looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body>
   <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>namespace mismatch require http://service.com found none</faultstring>
      <detail />
   </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As can figure out, there is a problem with the namespace, but i seems like no matter what I do, the problem still occurs.

I hope someone can see the problem and maybe can provide a solution.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, after trying for a loooong time, I finally got it to work.. and of course just right after posting this question, I got it to work. So here is the complete java code for the problem described in the question:

```
public class PayCheckHandler {

    public PayCheckHandler() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        String url = "http://localhost:8181/PayCheckHandlerMainWebService/services/RequestHandler?wsdl";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

        // print SOAP Response
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Response SOAP Message:");
        soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
        soapConnection.close();

    }


    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
            MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

            String serverURI = "http://service.com";

            // SOAP Envelope
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
            SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();


            // SOAP Body
            SOAPBodyElement element = body.addBodyElement(envelope.createName("echoTest", "", serverURI));
            element.addChildElement("echoString").addTextNode("Hello!!!");



            return soapMessage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new PayCheckHandler();
    }

}
```

Btw. if I absolutely didn't have to create my own SOAP messages manually, I would do as artem.ponchakov suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("echoTest","", serverURI);

SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("echoString","", serverURI);
```

But why are you constructing your SOAP explicitly?

If there is no particular reason, then use wsimport. Java classes + JAXB annotations will help you.

Comment: The only reason, is that it is a school project and it is required that I do it like that. Anyways, after trying for a loooong time, I finally got it to work.. and of course just right after posting this question on StackOverflow.
I appreciated your help though :) Thanks